# Populating a field based on values in other fields using ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.6

I would like to do a simple calculation using VB script or Python. Here is a screenshot of my field calculator which continuously seems to run into errors. Basically for the SITE CLASS field I would like to assign all the ST as "Optimal", all the WT as "Subsuitable" and all the CT as "Unsuitable".[image]

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all the text in the Pre-Logic Script Code box? Right now it's getting cut off, so it is hard to see what you are currently doing.

Comment: (You should always try to add the code as text instead of screenshots of it, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing SQL, VB and python syntax. Use python parser and:

Pre-Logic:

```
def reclass(siteclass):
    if 'ST' in siteclass:
        val = "Optimal"
    elif 'WT' in siteclass:
        val = "SubSuitable"
    else:
        val = "Unsuitable"
    return val
```

Call with

MACSITE_CL=

```
reclass(!SITE_CLASS!)
```